# Partition a Directory Tree By File Type

Tags: bash, shell

I have a directory tree containing files with a mix of extensions:

```
parent/
└── child1
    └── child2
        ├── A.1
        ├── B.1
        └── C.2
```

I'd like to partition the directory into two separate directories based on extension, e.g.:

```
parent.1/
└── child1
    └── child2
        ├── A.1
        └── B.1
```

And...

```
parent.2/
└── child1
    └── child2
        └── C.2
```

It doesn't really matter what the parent directory ends up being called as long as there are two unique trees. I'm only expecting two different file extensions.

Anyone able to help please?

Comment: please edit your to show what you have tried. You do know about the `mv` command? Why isn't that working for you? And I'm not sure this really qualifies as a programming Q. More appropriate to http://superuser.com . Good luck.

Comment: You can use `find` to find all files of name "*.2", then `mkdir -p parent2/$(dirname file)` followed by `mv file parent2/$(dirname file)`.

Answer (score 3):

`find` + `mkdir` + `mv` algorithm (with ***bash*** variable substitutions):

Let's say we have the following `parent` directory tree:

```
parent/
└── child1
    └── child2
        ├── A.1
        ├── B.1
        ├── C.2
        └── D.3
```

---

The job:

```
for f in $(find parent/ -type f); do 
    ext="${f##*.}"      # extracting file extension
    new_path="${f#*/}"  # preparing new file path
    mkdir -p "parent.$ext/${new_path%/*}"  # creating directory with crucial prefix
    mv "$f" "parent.$ext/$new_path"
done
```

---

Viewing results:

```
tree parent.[0-9]
```

The output:

```
parent.1
└── child1
    └── child2
        ├── A.1
        └── B.1
parent.2
└── child1
    └── child2
        └── C.2
parent.3
└── child1
    └── child2
        └── D.3
```

Answer (score 2):

Probably something like this:

- Find every *file* with extension ".ext2" in the parent1 tree.
- Ensure the directory path exists in parent2
- Move the file there.

.

```
parent1="/path/to/parent1"
pushd "$parent1"
find . -type f -iname "*.ext2" | while read filename; do
    mkdir -p "../parent2/$(dirname "$filename")"
    mv "$filename" "../parent2/$filename"
done
popd
```